# Launching node.js NPX from Eclipse Project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, eclipse, npx

I'm working on some web projects with Eclipse, node.js, React, JSX, and Babel. However whenever working on a project, it feels rather cumbersome to have to navigate to the project folder, open a command prompt, and then type in the command to launch Babel for compiling the JSX. For example, what I typically run at the project root:

```
npx babel --watch src --out-dir . --presets react-app/prod
```

So, I was wondering of there was a more simple method by which to launch a command window for the command from within Eclipse. Whether or not it opens a separate command prompt window or does so from within Eclipse (local terminal) I guess isn't too important. Either way, I'm not having much luck in determining if it's even possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, define an External Builder program: https://help.eclipse.org/2019-12/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-96_non_ant_pjs.htm?cp=0_1_2_2_0